# How to determine when buffering is finished on a HTML5 Audio element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, buffering, html5-audio

I'm trying to determine when the buffering has finished from a HTML5 audio element, but so far I can't find any `loadComplete` or similar event. I've tried using the progress event however it doesn't fire when finished downloading - only while downloading and therefore I can't use that to check. I've also tried the standard `load` event but that seems not to fire at all.

What other events are there that would allow me to check if buffering is finished, or would I have to use a timer to keep checking if `a.buffered.end(0) == a.duration`?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think there's such an event, at least at the moment. What would you like to do when the buffering is finished? May be you can approach the problem in a different manner.

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to implement a Flash-based program in Javascript and keep as much to the Flash version as possible. The Audio Data API isn't really an option as I'm developing for Chrome. Realistically, there should be a progressComplete or something event - but this must have been an oversight of the spec writers.

Comment: Came across this looking for something else. It's call canplaythrough. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Audio Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) provides an event called MozAudioAvailable which does what you need. This is in Firefox 4 only, but other modern browsers may implement it in the future.